# android開発　コルーチンの非同期スレッド実行中に、非同期スレッド内で取得したデータをディスプレイに表示する方法は？

Tags: android, samba, smb

android・コルーチンにおいて、非同期スレッドを実行中に、非同期スレッドで取得したデータをアンドロイドの画面に表示する方法をお教えください。

具体例として、jcifs-ng、コルーチンを使って、アンドロイド端末からSMBサーバーに接続してファイルをダウンロードする下記コードを書きました。
このコードにおいて、SMBサーバーに接続した時点でサーバーのファイルの情報（ファイル名とかサイズとか）をアンドロイドの画面に表示するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？
下記コードのconnectSmbDownload()関数内でのLogcat出力をアンドロイドの画面のTextView（tvInfo2）に表示させたいです。

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import jcifs.CIFSContext
import jcifs.config.PropertyConfiguration
import jcifs.context.BaseContext
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.util.*
import kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
    // 認証情報
    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Please replace these values to your data //
    val user = "USER"
    val password = "PASS"
    val domain = "192.168.1.1"
    val smbroot = "smb://" + domain + "/SMB/SERVER/FILE/"
    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    val TAG: String = "MySMB"

    // coroutine準備
    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + job

    // 終了時のcoroutineのキャンセル設定
    override fun onDestroy() {
        job.cancel()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val tvInfo1 = findViewById<View>(R.id.txtVwInfo1) as TextView
        val tvInfo2 = findViewById<View>(R.id.txtVwInfo2) as TextView
        val tvInfo3 = findViewById<View>(R.id.txtVwInfo3) as TextView

        launch {
            // output start-message in display
            tvInfo1.setText("Start!")

            // connect SMB server and download a file
            val localFile: File? = connectSmbDownload(user, password, domain, smbroot)

            // output finish message in display
            if (localFile != null) {
                tvInfo3.setText(localFile.length().toString() + "Byte downloaded.")
            } else {
                tvInfo3.setText( "no file downloaded.")
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun connectSmbDownload(user: String, password: String, domain: String, smbroot: String): File? {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // connect to SMB server
            val smb = connectSMB(user, password, domain, smbroot)
            Log.d(TAG, "Got SMB file: " + smb.path)

            // download a SMB file to android-device
            var downloadedFile: File? = null
            if (smb.isFile) {
                downloadedFile = cpSmbFile2android(smb)
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, smb.path + " is not a file.")
            }
            downloadedFile
        }
    }

    private suspend fun connectSMB(user: String, password: String, domain: String, smbroot: String): SmbFile {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val prop = Properties()
            prop.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.minVersion", "SMB202")
            prop.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.maxVersion", "SMB300")
            val bc = BaseContext(PropertyConfiguration(prop))
            val creds = NtlmPasswordAuthentication(bc, domain, user, password)
            val auth: CIFSContext = bc.withCredentials(creds)
            SmbFile(smbroot, auth)
        }
    }

    /*
     * リモートのSMBファイルをandroid端末にコピーする
     * 　コピー先は、android端末の外部ストレージのアプリキャッシュ領域
     *  smbFile  コピー元リモートのSMBファイル
     *  返り値　コピー先ファイル
     */
    private fun cpSmbFile2android(smbFile: SmbFile): File? {
        if ( !smbFile.isFile ) {
            return null
        }
        val fileName = smbFile.name
        val exterCacheFile = File(this.externalCacheDir!!.path + "/" + fileName)
        // copy remote smb-file to local
        val inStream = smbFile.openInputStream()
        val fileOutStream = FileOutputStream(exterCacheFile)
        val buf = ByteArray(1024)
        var len: Int = 0
        while (true) {
            len = inStream.read(buf)
            if (len < 0) break
            fileOutStream.write(buf)
        }
        fileOutStream.flush();
        fileOutStream.close();
        inStream.close();
        return exterCacheFile
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

自己レスです。
下記コードのように、非同期スレッドでの作業を1つのブロックにせず、メインスレッドにデータを渡したい場所の前後をそれぞれ別の関数とすることで非同期スレッド内のデータをメイスレッドに渡せました。
今回の例で言えば、SMBサーバーへの接続とファイルダウンロードを1つの関数にしていたのを、SMBサーバー接続関数とファイルダウンロード関数に分け、SMBサーバー接続関数実行後にサーバーファイルのパスをアンドロイド画面に表示し、次にファイルダウンロード関数を実行することで解決しました。
非同期スレッドの作業状況をプログレスバーで表示するようなことはどうすればよいか未だわかりませんので、お教えくだされば助かります。

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import jcifs.CIFSContext
import jcifs.config.PropertyConfiguration
import jcifs.context.BaseContext
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.util.*
import kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
    // 認証情報
    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Please replace these values to your data //
    val user = "USER"
    val password = "PASS"
    val domain = "192.168.1.1"
    val smbroot = "smb://" + domain + "/SMB/SERVER/FILE/"
    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    val TAG: String = "MySMB"
    var tmpStr: String = ""

    // coroutine準備
    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + job

    // 終了時のcoroutineのキャンセル設定
    override fun onDestroy() {
        job.cancel()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val tvInfo1 = findViewById<View>(R.id.txtVwInfo1) as TextView
        val tvInfo2 = findViewById<View>(R.id.txtVwInfo2) as TextView
        val tvInfo3 = findViewById<View>(R.id.txtVwInfo3) as TextView

        launch {
            // output start-message in display
            tvInfo1.setText("Start!")

            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                // connect SMB
                val smb: SmbFile = connectSmb(user, password, domain, smbroot)
                tmpStr = java.lang.String.format("Got SMB file: %s", smb.path)
                tvInfo2.setText(tmpStr)

                // download a file from SMB to android
                val localFile: File? = cpSmbFile2android(smb)
                if ( null == localFile ) {
                    tmpStr = java.lang.String.format("Can't download: %s", smb.path)
                    tvInfo3.setText(tmpStr)
                } else {
                    tmpStr = java.lang.String.format("Downloaded %s. %sByte", smb.path, localFile.length())
                    tvInfo3.setText(tmpStr)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun connectSmb(user: String, password: String, domain: String, smbroot: String): SmbFile {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val prop = Properties()
            prop.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.minVersion", "SMB202")
            prop.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.maxVersion", "SMB300")
            val bc = BaseContext(PropertyConfiguration(prop))
            val creds = NtlmPasswordAuthentication(bc, domain, user, password)
            val auth: CIFSContext = bc.withCredentials(creds)
            SmbFile(smbroot, auth)
        }
    }

    /*
     * リモートのSMBファイルをandroid端末にコピーする
     * 　コピー先は、android端末の外部ストレージのアプリキャッシュ領域
     *  smbFile  コピー元リモートのSMBファイル
     *  返り値　コピー先ファイル
     */
    private fun cpSmbFile2android(smbFile: SmbFile): File? {
        if ( !smbFile.isFile ) {
            return null
        }
        val fileName = smbFile.name
        val exterCacheFile = File(this.externalCacheDir!!.path + "/" + fileName)
        // copy remote smb-file to local
        val inStream = smbFile.openInputStream()
        val fileOutStream = FileOutputStream(exterCacheFile)
        val buf = ByteArray(1024)
        var len: Int = 0
        while (true) {
            len = inStream.read(buf)
            if (len < 0) break
            fileOutStream.write(buf)
        }
        fileOutStream.flush();
        fileOutStream.close();
        inStream.close();
        return exterCacheFile
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

自己レスです。
lifecycleScopeを使って、非同期スレッドでの処理中にandroid端末画面にプログレスバーを表示することができました。
次のコードです。

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import jcifs.CIFSContext
import jcifs.config.PropertyConfiguration
import jcifs.context.BaseContext
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.util.*
import kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
    // 認証情報
    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Please replace these values to your data //
    val user = ""
    val password = ""
    val domain = "192.168.1.1"
    val smbroot = "smb://" + domain + "/SMB/SERVER/FILE/"
    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    val TAG: String = "MySMB"
    var tmpStr: String = ""

    // coroutine準備
    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + job

    // 終了時のcoroutineのキャンセル設定
    override fun onDestroy() {
        job.cancel()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val tvInfo1 = findViewById<View>(R.id.txtVwInfo1) as TextView
        val tvInfo2 = findViewById<View>(R.id.txtVwInfo2) as TextView
        val tvInfo3 = findViewById<View>(R.id.txtVwInfo3) as TextView
        val prgrsBar = findViewById<View>(R.id.progressBar) as ProgressBar

        tvInfo1.setText("Start!")

        // Display prograssBar in the screen
        prgrsBar.visibility = ProgressBar.VISIBLE

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val smb: SmbFile = connectSmb(user, password, domain, smbroot)
            tmpStr = java.lang.String.format("Got SMB file: %s", smb.path)
            tvInfo2.setText(tmpStr)

            // download a file from SMB to android
            val localFile: File = cpSmbFile2android(smb)

            // Turn off prograssBar in the screen
            prgrsBar.visibility = ProgressBar.INVISIBLE

            tmpStr = java.lang.String.format("Downloaded %s. %sByte", smb.path, localFile.length())
            tvInfo3.setText(tmpStr)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun connectSmb(user: String, password: String, domain: String, smbroot: String): SmbFile {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val prop = Properties()
            prop.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.minVersion", "SMB202")
            prop.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.maxVersion", "SMB300")

            val smbConnection = runCatching {
                val bc = BaseContext(PropertyConfiguration(prop))
                val creds = NtlmPasswordAuthentication(bc, domain, user, password)
                val auth: CIFSContext = bc.withCredentials(creds)
                SmbFile(smbroot, auth)
            }
            smbConnection.getOrElse {
                throw Exception("connectSmb failed.")
            }

            /* このコードでもOK
            return@withContext runCatching {
                val bc = BaseContext(PropertyConfiguration(prop))
                val creds = NtlmPasswordAuthentication(bc, domain, user, password)
                val auth: CIFSContext = bc.withCredentials(creds)
                SmbFile(smbroot, auth)
            }
            .getOrElse {
                throw Exception("connectSmb failed.")
            }
            */
        }
    }

    /*
     * リモートのSMBファイルをandroid端末にコピーする
     * 　コピー先は、android端末の外部ストレージのアプリキャッシュ領域
     *  smbFile  コピー元リモートのSMBファイル
     *  返り値　コピー先ファイル
     */
    private suspend fun cpSmbFile2android(smbFile: SmbFile): File {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            if (!smbFile.isFile) {
                null
            }
            val fileName = smbFile.name
            val exterCacheFile = File( this@MainActivity.externalCacheDir!!.path + "/" + fileName)
            // copy remote smb-file to local
            return@withContext runCatching {
                val inStream = smbFile.openInputStream()
                val fileOutStream = FileOutputStream(exterCacheFile)
                val buf = ByteArray(1024)
                var len: Int = 0
                while (true) {
                    len = inStream.read(buf)
                    if (len < 0) break
                    fileOutStream.write(buf)
                }
                fileOutStream.flush();
                fileOutStream.close();
                inStream.close();
                exterCacheFile
            }
            .getOrElse {
                throw Exception("downloadSmb2Android failed.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

自己レスです。
進行状況を表示するプログレスバーの表示他をViewModel、LiveData、ViewModelScopeで行えましたので、下記に掲載します。

MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import net.sytes.rokkosan.smbclient2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Please replace these values to your data //

    val DOMAIN: String = "192.168.1.1"
    val SMBROOT: String = "/SMB/SERVER/FILE/"
    val USER: String = ""
    val PASSWORD: String = ""

    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    lateinit var androidPath: String
    lateinit var smbViewModel: SmbViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        var isSmb: Boolean = false
        binding.progBarHori.max = 100

        // prepare for connecting SMB server
        var smbUrl = "smb://" + DOMAIN + SMBROOT
        if (smbUrl.takeLast(1) != "/") {
            smbUrl += "/"
            // smbUrl文字列の末尾はスラッシュ（/）にしておく
        }

        // get the cache directory in android device
        androidPath = externalCacheDir!!.absolutePath

        // get ViewModel for SmbConnection
        val smbViewModelFactory = SmbViewModelFactory(USER, PASSWORD, DOMAIN, smbUrl, androidPath)
        smbViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, smbViewModelFactory).get(SmbViewModel::class.java)

        // Create observers which updates the UI.
        val pathObserver = Observer<String> { sPath ->
            // Update the UI
            binding.tvSmbPath.text = sPath
        }
        val sizeObserver = Observer<Long> { sSize ->
            // Update the UI
            binding.tvSmbSize.text = (sSize / 1000L).toString() + "KB"
        }
        val downloadedRatioObserver = Observer<Int> { dRatio ->
            // Update the UI
            binding.progBarHori.progress = dRatio
        }
        val isConnectedObserver = Observer<Boolean> { isConnected ->
            if (!isConnected) {
                isSmb = false
                binding.tvInfo01.setText(R.string.failedConnectSmb)
            } else {
                isSmb = true

                /*
                 * get data in SMB server
                 *     参考ページ　https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata?hl=ja
                 */
                // Observe the LiveData, passing in this activity as the LifecycleOwner and the observer.
                //   observe(Owner, ...)のOwnerは、Activityの時はthis、Fragmentの時はviewLifecycleOwnerとする
                smbViewModel.smbPath.observe(this, pathObserver)
                smbViewModel.smbSize.observe(this, sizeObserver)

                // Display prograssBar in the screen
                smbViewModel.downloadedRatio.observe(this, downloadedRatioObserver)
                binding.progBarHori.visibility = ProgressBar.VISIBLE
            }
        }

        // connect SMB server and download a file to android device
        binding.tvInfo01.setText(R.string.wait)
        smbViewModel.downloadSmbFile()

        // proceed according to smbViewModel.isConnectedSmb
        smbViewModel.isConnectedSmb.observe(this,isConnectedObserver)
        if (!isSmb) {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

SmbViewModel.kt

```kotlin
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import jcifs.config.PropertyConfiguration
import jcifs.context.BaseContext
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthenticator
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.util.*

class SmbViewModel(val user: String, val password: String, val domain: String, val smbUrl: String, val androidPath: String): ViewModel() {
    // LiveDataを設定する
    private val _smbPath: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<String>()
    }
    val smbPath: LiveData<String>
        get() = _smbPath

    private val _smbSize: MutableLiveData<Long> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<Long>()
    }
    val smbSize: LiveData<Long>
        get() = _smbSize

    private val _isConnectedSmb = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isConnectedSmb: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _isConnectedSmb

    private var _downloadedRatio: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData<Int>().also {
            mutableLiveData -> mutableLiveData.value = -1
    }
    public val downloadedRatio: LiveData<Int> get() = _downloadedRatio

    // SMBサーバーへの接続、ファイルダウンロード
    fun downloadSmbFile() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            lateinit var smb: SmbFile

            // connect to SMB server
            try {
                val prop = Properties()  // java.util.Properties
                prop.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.minVersion", "SMB202")
                prop.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.maxVersion", "SMB300")
                val baseCxt = BaseContext(PropertyConfiguration(prop))
                val auth =
                    baseCxt.withCredentials(NtlmPasswordAuthenticator(domain, user, password))
                smb = SmbFile(smbUrl, auth)
                if (!smb.exists()) {
                    _isConnectedSmb.postValue(false)
                    return@launch
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _isConnectedSmb.postValue(false)
                return@launch
            }

            _isConnectedSmb.postValue(true)

            // LiveDataにSMBサーバーからのデータをセットする
            _smbPath.postValue(smb.path)
            _smbSize.postValue(smb.length())

            // download a file from SMB server to android device
            val fileName = smb.name
            val fileSize = smb.length()
            val exterCacheFile = File(androidPath + "/" + fileName)
            val inStream = smb.openInputStream()
            val fileOutStream = FileOutputStream(exterCacheFile)
            val buf = ByteArray(1024)
            var len = 0
            var downloadedSize = 0L
            while (true) {
                len = inStream.read(buf)
                if (len < 0) {
                    break
                }
                downloadedSize += len.toLong()
                _downloadedRatio.postValue((downloadedSize * 100L / fileSize).toInt())
                fileOutStream.write(buf)
            }
            fileOutStream.flush();
            fileOutStream.close();
            inStream.close()
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelScope.cancel()
    }
}
```

SmbViewModelFactory.kt

```kotlin
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

class SmbViewModelFactory(val user: String, val password: String, val domain: String, val smbUrl: String, val androidPath: String): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return SmbViewModel(user, password, domain, smbUrl, androidPath) as T
    }
}
```